# How do I get setState to update a value immediately?

Tags: react-native, setstate

I have to press the buttons twice to update the filter value for how I want to display the movies in my app. This is my code:

```
 const HomeScreen = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovies();
  },[])

  useEffect(() => {
    getMoviesFiltered(filter);
  },[filter])

  const [filter, setFilter] = useState('name');

  const getMovies = async (filter) =>{
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(query(collection(db, "movies"), orderBy(filter)));
    setMovies(querySnapshot.docs);
  }


  return (
      <View>
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {setFilter('name'); getMovies(filter)}}>
        <Text>Title</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {setFilter('runtime'); getMovies(filter)}}>
        <Text>Runtime</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {setFilter('year'); getMovies(filter)}}>
        <Text>Year</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      </View>

 <FlatList
  data = {movies}
  renderItem = {({item}) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Modal', item.data())}>
    <Image source={{uri: item.data().pic}}/>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
  />
  </View>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

I know that setState is asynchronous and that that is the reason it happens, but I'm kind of stuck on not knowing how to change it properly, so I'd appreaciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` will run when the values within dependency array change.

So, you don't need to add function `getMovies` after you changed your filter. Just simply move that to `useEffect`.

```
const HomeScreen = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState({});
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState('name');

  useEffect(() => {
    //when page is initialize, run this
    getMovies(filter);
  },[])

  useEffect(() => {
    //when filter is changed, use latest value to run this
    getMovies(filter);
  },[filter]);

  const getMovies = async (filter) =>{
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(query(collection(db, "movies"), orderBy(filter)));
    setMovies(querySnapshot.docs);
  }

  return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {setFilter('name');}}>
          <Text>Title</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {setFilter('runtime');}}>
          <Text>Runtime</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {setFilter('year');}}>
          <Text>Year</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      
        <FlatList
          data = {movies}
          renderItem = {({item}) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Modal', item.data())}>
              <Image source={{uri: item.data().pic}}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            )
          }
        />
    </View>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```